# My 07 Nissan Pathfinder won't start but lights still work

Tags: starting, nissan, pathfinder

My 07 Nissan Pathfinder won't start, all lights turn on (headlights, dashboard) radio and fan work. There's no noise when I turn the key to start the truck, what can it be? It completely shut down

Comment: Had a similar problem with 2006 Lexus RX, the issue was broken key. The metal part was separate from the plastic fob with buttons and it wouldn't start unless the fob was held very close to the keyhole. If it's not the case, can you please tell how/when the issue started occurring?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Try putting into drive and then into park a few times.  Also try starting in neutral. There may be an issue with the park/neutral safety switch, or the gear selector alignment with that switch